# How does flutter doctor detect what ide is installed

Tags: windows, flutter, cmd

When running flutter on windows server 2016, doctor is showing VS as not installed. If someone could point me in source as to how flutter detects ide's(my understanding is that they use default locations - not environment vars), that would be helpful.

Comment: most likely it is done here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/windows/visual_studio.dart (or other `visual_studio*.dart` file)

Comment: Is your question really about Visual Studio, which is only checked if you turn on the preview Windows desktop support, or about VS Code?

Comment: @pskink, TY, that answered my question perfectly!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink for locating it; sorry it took me so long to respond back.

location as of: v1.15.9
[GitHub Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/windows/visual_studio.dart)

Found that flutter calls vswhere.exe to resolve location and version information.

EX:

```
$vsw_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe";
$vsw_raw_data = (& $vsw_path -version 16);
$vsw_sdata = @{};
$vsw_ins_start = 3;
$vsw_ins_stop = $vsw_raw_data.Count - $vsw_ins_start; 
do {
  $k,$v = (($vsw_raw_data[$vsw_ins_start]) -Split ':\s');
  $vsw_sdata.add($k,$v); ++$vsw_ins_start
} while ($vsw_ins_start -ne $vsw_ins_stop); 
$vsw_sdata.productPath
```

Additionally, it passes '-required' parameters to verify if certain packages are installed, etc: [Github VSWhere](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere)

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.